# Make Responsive Svg inside angular-gridster item

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, gridster

I want to make Gridster grid responsive according to grid resize as well as window resize. Currently I am using DC.js to render charts inside the gridster grid, but if the screen resolution changes from bigger to smaller ,  the value of the item stored previously for the width for svg remain too big for the screen.

Any tips how to make it responsive. How to set the width of gridster item , it looks to me it injected through java-script.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. Angular Gridster have a event "gridster-resized" , whenever this event happens try to resize the items in the gridster.